16bit grayscale satellite image not visible in OpenTK
I want to show 16bit grayscale satellite image with OpenTK on WPF.
I finally finished making bitmap as WriteableBitmap. When I save it as png and open with Qgis, there is no problem with the bitmap but when I set Texture and watch with OpenTK there is only black window appeared in my WPF.
Is there any problem with this code? If I need to fix it, how should I fix it?
Here is the code of the Texture:

public static int GenTextureID(WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
    int id = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

    bmp.Lock();
    unsafe
    {
        try
        {

            
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D
                                , 0
                                , PixelInternalFormat.Luminance
                                , (int)bmp.Width
                                , (int)bmp.Height
                                , 0
                                , OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Luminance
                                , PixelType.UnsignedShort
                                , bmp.BackBuffer);

        }
        finally
        {
            bmp.Unlock();
        }
    }
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter,(int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
    
    return id;
}

